# Risks of using a cast iron skillet on a flat/glass top electric range?

Tags: physics, cooking

There are many claims about possible risks of [cooking](/questions/tagged/cooking) with a cast iron skillet on a [flat/glass top electric range](http://www.appliancist.com/samsung-range-electric-ftq387.jpg):

1. the glass top can break if one is not careful;
2. the glass can be scratched;
3. the [glass top can melt](http://www.thathomesite.com/forums/load/cookware/msg010049447701.html?20);
4. the skillet can be prone to hot spots, producing uneven cooking; and
5. the hot spots can [cause damage to the skillet itself](http://whatscookingamerica.net/Information/CeramicTopRange.htm).

[This topic has been discussed before](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4734/using-cast-iron-on-a-glass-range) on [cooking.sx](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) (perhaps this question should be cross-listed over there too?), but that thread didn't cite any sources and, well, I am a skeptic.  Also, that thread did not address the possibility of damage to the skillet (claim #5 above).

I think claims 1 and 2 are reasonable given the coarse texture and heavy weight of some cast iron skillets, however, [this answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4734/using-cast-iron-on-a-glass-range#9394) seems to refute them.  Claim 3 seems unlikely.  Claims 4 and 5 seem to be open questions.

I'm interested because I used to live in an apartment with a glass-top electric range and I sometimes used a cast iron skillet on it.  I was diligent about avoiding sliding *any* pots/pans on the surface of the glass, not only my cast iron skillet.  The glass surface did develop some minor scratches on the surface, so I am wondering if that was due to my infrequent use of a cast iron skillet.

**Are there any studies that document possible risks in using a cast-iron skillet on a glass-top electric range?**

Comment: I've focused the question, hopefully without distorting it, so we avoid mere speculation :-)